# Alert for empty field in table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a table and added a button 'Add Row' which will clone the row of the table and append it with the previous row. I have put an alert for which if any of the fields is left empty then user should not be able to add a new row.It seems to be working when i hard-coded the drop down values. Now since I am fetching my drop down values from the local db it always shows alert("Please fill all the fields in the current row") after filling all the fields. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

```````````````````````jQuery``````````````````````````

```
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
var cindex = 0;
$(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(e) {

  var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
  if(count || !$('select:last').val()){
    alert("Please fill all the fields in the current row");
    return false;
  }
    var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
    var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
    cindex++;
    $clone.find(':input').not('select').not('.DeleteButton').val('').attr('disabled', true);
    $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
    //update ids of elements in row
    $clone.find("*").each(function() {
        var id = this.id || "";
        if(id != ""){

        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
        if (match.length == 2) {
        this.id = this.name + (cindex);
        }
        }
    });
    $tr.after($clone);
});
```

`HTML`

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id01" name="row">
      <td><select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <xsl:for-each select="{Values fetching from local db}">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description"/>
            <option value="{code}"> <xsl:value-of select="description"/> </option>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </select></td>
      <td><input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  /></td>
      <td><input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  /></td>
      <td><input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  /></td>
      <td><input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton"  type="button" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input tabindex="6" id="Button5" value="Initiate" class="buttons" name="Button5" type="button" onClick="return fnOnSubmit();"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You always getting count value. why you use it?

Comment: check what '$('select:last').val()' returns in browser console.

Comment: I have added my code in fiddle. Please do have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/2ekdrt61/

Comment: your fiddle is not working correctly

Comment: @Mamun can you please help. Thanks.

Comment: since i couldn't get values from db, i had added hardcoded values to your select element. After selecting a value and populating all 3 textboxes, row is being added successfully. you could use debugger; to check what value your 'select' or count is returning after fetching values from db.

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider my alert is working fine for the hard-coded values but not when i am fetching values from db

Comment: @Saurav use debugger; in your code to analyze what value your controls are returning when Add new row button is clicked.